# Lucene Document Container with Null Fields

Tags: java, lucene

I have a desktop application that
 implements the lucene 3.6.2 search engine
 for database search.
 The database contains columns 
  with both date and char data types
. Some columns can also contain null fields.
  Datetools is also used to convert Date to 
String for analysis by Lucene 
 However looks like when lucene is not 
able to add null fields from the 
 date columns to the Document container
for analysis.

I present code snippets below:

```
 doc = new Document();


         if(rs.getDate("DATE_OF_LETTER")== null)
         { doc.add(new Field("date_of_letter","",Field.Store.YES,Field.Index.ANALYZED)); }
         else {
        doc.add(new Field("date_of_letter",DateTools.dateToString(rs.getDate("DATE_OF_LETTER"),
                DateTools.Resolution.DAY),Field.Store.YES,Field.Index.ANALYZED)); 
         }       

        if(rs.getDate("DATE_RECEIVED")== null)
         { doc.add(new Field("date_received","",Field.Store.YES,Field.Index.ANALYZED)); }
        else {
          doc.add(new Field("date_received",DateTools.dateToString(rs.getDate("DATE_RECEIVED"),
                DateTools.Resolution.DAY),Field.Store.YES,Field.Index.ANALYZED));  
        }      

         if(rs.getString("REMARKS")== null)
         { doc.add(new Field("remarks","",Field.Store.YES,Field.Index.ANALYZED)); }
         else {
         doc.add(new Field("remarks",rs.getString("REMARKS"),Field.Store.YES,Field.Index.ANALYZED));  }

          if(rs.getDate("DATE_DISPATCHED")== null)
         { doc.add(new Field("date_dispatched","",Field.Store.YES,Field.Index.ANALYZED)); }
         else {
        doc.add(new Field("date_dispatched",DateTools.dateToString(rs.getDate("DATE_DISPATCHED"),
                DateTools.Resolution.MINUTE),Field.Store.YES,Field.Index.ANALYZED)); 

                }     
           }
         iw.addDocument(doc);
         }



   }
```

any suggestion.

Comment: Do you get any error or is the fields value just null when you inspect the index afterwards?

Comment: I don't get an error at the netbeans console , even though there are hits but lucene does not return any result. And please how do I inspect the index please am new to lucene

Comment: There is a tool where you can inspect the index: http://www.getopt.org/luke/ - have a look at it and check if the fields are set in the lucene index.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
doc.add(new Field("date_received","",Field.Store.YES,Field.Index.ANALYZED));
```

Doesn't really do anything.  There is nothing to index.  It might store the field (I'm not sure, right off), but it certainly won't be indexed in any way, and so won't be searchable.  Lucene indexes tokens, and an empty string has no tokens, and so there is nothing to index, nothing to search with.

If you wish to be able to search for nulls, you should index a placeholder value for them, such as;

```
doc.add(new Field("date_received","null",Field.Store.YES,Field.Index.ANALYZED));
```